# jQuery - click event -> too much recursion

Tags: jquery, events, recursion, callback

I have the following code:

```
function display_content(clicked_node_id) {

   // (...) //

   for(j=0; j<conn_nodes.length; j++) {
      var node_id = JSON.stringify(conn_nodes[j]['conn_node_id']);
      content_all_connections += "<a id=\""+node_id+"\">"+conn_node_label+"<\/a>;
      $('#'+node_id).click(display_content(node_id));
   }
   document.getElementById('all-connections').innerHTML = content_all_connections;
}
```

This function is embedded in a callback function so that it's not in the global scope.

When I then click on this `<a>` link either nothing happens at all or sometimes it tells me "too much recursion". All tries with stopPropagation or similar failed.

Please, could you give me a hint where my mistake is.

Comment: Can you show your HTML or full code with jsfiddle?

Comment: You're *calling* `display_content(node_id)` and passing its result to `click()` instead of a closure that calls it. Infinite recursion ensues.

Comment: Yes that is indeed my problem. Could you tell me how to do it correctly? O:-) Thank you!!